# Continuity and derivative square integrable implies Holder continuity?

Tags: fourier-analysis, holder-spaces

Let $f\in\mathcal{C}^{0}$ such that $f'\in\mathcal{L}^{2}[a,b]$. How can i show that $f$ is Hölder?

My attempt: Assuming that i can apply the fundamental theorem of calculus,i was able to find that $f$ is Holder,but i can not prove that in fact,for any $x,y\in[a,b]$ i can apply the theorem on $f'$.

Comment: Hint: Cauchy schwarz on $|f(y) - f(x)| \le \int_x^y |f'(t)|\cdot 1$ for $a\le x\le y \le b$.

Comment: You'll need to assume more because there are non-decreasing functions on $[a,b]$ with $f'=0$ a.e., and yet $f$ is not Holder continuous.

Comment: @TrialAndError the cantor function is not differentiable. In fact, **everywhere** differentiable and integrable derivative imply AC on compact intervals. Cf theorem 20 in http://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/6337/fall07/section3.5b.pdf

Comment: @user251257 : The Cantor function is differentiable almost everywhere, as is every monotone function on an interval. Remember we're talking about $L^2$ here; so a.e. is the name of the game. That's why I asked for clarification.

Comment: @TrialAndError sorry, it sounded a little bit harsch. But, if someone writes $f'$ without explanation, I assume existence **everywhere**.

Comment: @user251257 : But $f' \in L^2$ adds ambiguity.

Comment: @TrialAndError that is true.

Comment: @user251257 : I think you should post your hint as an answer, and state your assumption. It's better for the site to have questions answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. The derivative $f'$ is also $L^1$ as $[a,b]$ has finite measure.
2. If $f$ is actually **everywhere** differentiable, then $f$ is absolutely continuous.
3. By fundamental theorem of calculus we have for $a\le x \le y \le b$
   $$ |f(y) - f(x)| \le \int_x^y 1 \cdot |f'(t)| \; dt. $$
4. Apply Cauchy Schwarz on the right hand side.